# How to add and remove div with posts between table rows angularjs ?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a table with staff are represented as a table. I would like by click on item show list with comments for current employee with input below to support adding new comment.

In my directive I try to write a new element or delete all of the depends on state flag. When I decide to support many comments I made a sophisticated code with open\closed tags and my dataset inside them. I do this because I would like to have an id for container which can be found a deleted with all children like this:

```
                var feedback = document.getElementById(id);
                feedback.remove();
```

But when angular create and add my element (which is made open) in the output it is closed automatically and all my dataset are represented such as nest elements. Below I show just a simplified example what I have right now:

```
   var closeTag = angular.element(
                        '<div>' +
                            '<input id="name" type="text" ng-model="feedbackValue" ng-minlength="1" required>' +
                            '<input add-new-team type="submit" value="Add new feedback">' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
            '</div>'
    );

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.state = 'off';
            $scope.toggle = function() {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    console.log($element.children().length);
                    var name = $element.children()[0].attributes["data-value"].value;
                    var feedbackSet = teamSharedObj.feedback[name];
                    var id = "feedBackFor" + name.replace(/\s+/g, '');;
                    var openTag = angular.element(
                            '<div id=' + id + '>' +
                                '</tr><tr>' +
                                    '<td colspan="4">'

                    );
                    $compile(openTag)($scope);
                    $element.after(openTag);
                    $scope.state = ($scope.state === 'on' ? 'off' : 'on');
                    if ($scope.state === "on") {
                        console.log("Feedback " + feedbackSet);
                        if (typeof feedbackSet === "undefined") {
                            var noFeedback = angular.element(
                                    '<div id="feedbackContainer">' +
                                    "No information. Does he work on any project?" +
                                    '</div>'
                            );
                            $compile(openTag)($scope);
                            $element.after(openTag);
                            $compile(noFeedback)($scope);
                            openTag.after(noFeedback);
                            $compile(closeTag)($scope);
                            noFeedback.after(closeTag);
                            return;
                        }

//                        // TODO show all feed rows, setup id as a name

                    } else {
                        // TODO destroy a div container as a name
                        console.log("state is off");
                        var feedback = document.getElementById(id);
                        feedback.remove();
                    }
                });
            };
            this.getState = function() {
                return $scope.state;
            };
        },
        link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                scope.toggle();
            });
        }
```

The question is how to show and maintain collection of elements from directive dynamically and how to delete them? Do you now simpler or more natural way for angular to do that?

Comment: I don't think you are using the directive in the easiest fashion... a controller is shared among instances of a directive (so if you have two or more, you may get unexpected results. This also forces you to use $compile where the linking function would do the work for you when mixed with a template and ng-if ng-show.

Comment: So to address your question more directly, you should use a template in your directive which uses ng-repeat to repeat a collection of objects. Then use ng-show or ng-if to dynamically hide/delete them based on a flag or condition.

Comment: I don't mean to offend, but it looks like you're doing things the hard way. Can you post a plunker with some code in it and the community (including me) might help you out? Here is a blank template to get you started: http://plnkr.co/edit/GGU2QRS5kzxIMk0UcPFX?p=info (just fork it and you'll be able to modify it)

Comment: Thank you. I followed your advice and replace all this on controller